# How to call a function using dictionary key Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, operators

Here I am trying to call a function using dictionary key value.

```
>>> def hello():
        print('hello')

>>> a = {'+': hello()}
```

it just prints **hello** after executing this line.

```
>>> a['+']
```

If I call the dictionary using key value, it results nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put () while you are using the function name as a value for the dictionary because as soon as python find () it will execute the function.
Instead just add the function name `a = {'+': hello}`

And then use the () while fetching the value from the dictionary

`a["+"]()`

Comment: Also using **return 'hello'** instead of **print('hello')** solves this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a return call.

```
def hello():
    return 'hello'
```

Or I think that is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You should put your callable as the value into the dict and **then** call it.

```
>>> def hello():
        print('hello')

>>> a = {'+': hello}

>>> a['+']()
hello
```